# Angular 12 access template place holder from child

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router

We have a root component that contains the base layout of a page.  ie
Header, foot, sidebar and main content

```
<main class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
```

Based on a route, we are looking for a way to push components into the side bar, possibly by using templates? ie, template place holder within the root component, and pass a template in using :-

```
<ng-template #sidepanel>
<div>here is the side panel content </div
```

tried to google, but only finding ways to pass from parent to child.

Comment: There are multiple ways. As mentioned by Dariusz, you can use CDK portal Or you can use a service to emit and subscribe `TemplateRef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is CDK Portals, unfortunately the answer is not simple and would be too long for stack overflow. I'd recommend reading those blog posts and analyzing code examples described there:

- https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-cdk-portals-b02f66dd020c
- https://juristr.com/blog/2018/05/dynamic-UI-with-cdk-portals/
- https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use a service to manage the state of the application.
How can you do it?
Create a service with a behavior subject

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StateService {
  // I just create a subject for a string but you can create for eveything
  // that you want, primitives values string, number, object, custom object
  // arrays, etc
  readonly commentSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  readonly comment$ = this.commentSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateComment(value: string) {
    this.commentSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Then in your components you can update that comment by updated the subject

```js
// component for route 1
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private stateService: StateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stateService.updateComment('New comment from one component');
  }
}

// component for route 2
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private stateService: StateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stateService.updateComment('New comment from second component');
  }
}
```

After that you just need to subscribe inside of the side bar to that observable

```js
export class SidebarComponent {
  comment$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private stateService: StateService) {
    this.comment$ = this.stateService.comment$;
  }
}

//And in your HTML you can use async pipe to show the value of that observable
<p>Comment: {{ comment$ | async }}</p>
```